# Extend Twig Template - how to do this in PHP?

Tags: php, twig, fuelphp

I'm currently looking for the class defining twig's 'extends' tag.

Background: I use Twig alongside FuelPHP to create my templates. However, I ran into a brick wall when I modularized features (moved them from the basic app folder into modules/....).

The Filesystem Loader of twig picks the first template with the name supplied, not regarding module context.

I want to pass extends a second parameter and set the template search path based on that.

I'd be happy if someone points me towards the right class

EDIT - An example of what I am trying to do with extends (this does the same for include): http://pastebin.com/Er2wJX9k

Comment: you need your code to clarify this.

Comment: share your code with some explanation. No one can provide you a solution to your problem if you did not provide full information

Comment: @altafhussain I'm trying to do something like http://pastebin.com/Er2wJX9k, which takes the module name, limits the template path to the views folder of the module and then uses getSource to get the template, without having to mess with the basic app config.  Now I'm trying to achieve the same with extends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not looking for the class that implements the `{% extends "some_path" %}` tag, you're looking the one that interprets the `"some_path"` part to get the right twig file from.

Each time a twig template is required, the [Loader](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#loaders) you specified when initializing your environment is used to get the content of a twig file from a string. Twig comes with 2 built-in loaders: the `Twig_Loader_FileSystem` is used to get twig files from a specified path, and the `Twig_Loader_String` is used when you give twig code instead of a template name.

You can develop your own `Twig Loader`, by implementing both `Twig_LoaderInterface` and `Twig_ExistsLoaderInterface` interfaces. Just look at the existing ones, located in `twig/lib/Twig/Loader` directory, and implement your own Loader as you want. For instance, `$name` argument will contain a template "path" (for example, Module:template.twig), and after applying your custom logic, you can return the content of the right `template.twig` file.

Comment: I was looking at a quick and dirty solution, as explained above. I've chopped together a similiar function for include, as per http://pastebin.com/Er2wJX9k . and I am looking at doing this for extends as well.  While in theory your approach would be the better one, it might be over the top for just a small town project like mine.

Comment: Then, continue to use the `Loader_FileSystem` and add namespaces for each module. `$loader->addPath("path/to/module/templates", 'moduleName');`, and then do `{% extends '@moduleName/template.twig' %}`.

Comment: Hm, yeah, sounds feasible.  Thank you.